# how to get the timer counted value in Android?

Tags: android, timer

How to create an android mobile application that will do a counting in miliseconds (start from 0), and ask user to type"I Like to eat" in EditText and click submit. After user click submit, counting will stop and a dialog box will appear and show the counting result.

```
   package com.example.labex4;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,displayValue;
    EditText nameTxt;
    Button button1;
    int count = 0;
    Timer T;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        T=new Timer();
        T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        displayValue.setText("count="+count);
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1);

        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        displayValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayValue);
        nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         T.cancel();
        dialog.editext.setText(""+count);
    }
}


***Here is The XML file***

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="(Type Faster)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Miliseconds: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="displayvalue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Type this words: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Frankie Jones Anak Saing"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="Check" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post what you have already tried

Comment: i already try do the interface only..This is a part in mainActivity...

Comment: i already put the code that i have...@DavidJohns

Answer (score 0):

Global Variable

```
int count = 0;
Timer T;
```

Put the below code in onCreate after setContentView

```
T=new Timer();
        T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        //myTextView.setText("count="+count);
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1);
```

At Button OnCLick

**UPDATE**

```
 T.cancel();
    //Open popup or dialog or alert as per your choice and print the count value
    //dialog.editext.setText(""+count);

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(<YourActivityName>this).create(); //Read Update
        alertDialog.setTitle("You total time count");
        alertDialog.setMessage(String.valueof(count));

        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // here you can add functions
               alertDialog.dismiss();
           }
        });

        alertDialog.show();  //<-- See This!
    }
```

**As Per Your Requirement I am pasting the whole class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,displayValue;
    EditText nameTxt;
    Button button1;
    int count = 0;
    Timer T;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        T=new Timer();
        T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        displayValue.setText("count="+count);
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1);

        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        displayValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayValue);
        nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        T.cancel();
        //Open popup or dialog or alert as per your choice and print the count value
        //dialog.editext.setText(""+count);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);
        dialog.setTitle("Typing Result!");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView titletext = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
        //titletext.setText("Typing Result!");
        titletext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Frankie Jones Igat, Your Typing Speed "+String.valueOf(count)+" miliseconds");
        Button dialogButtonOK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButtonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

**And Custom pop up layout in layout folder custom_popup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titletext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titletext"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="titlekiefsjisejefsjeaij"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @FrankieJonesIgat I updated the code for opening the android default alert poup with total count. Please check

Comment: in you code @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //put the updated code
    }

Comment: <YourActivityName>this).create()...what i need to put here..?..if my activitty name is LabEx4, so i need to put name..its correct.?

Comment: put yourclassname.this. In your case MainActivity.this. Put htis MainActivity.this every where where this is written.

Comment: Correct. If your activitty name is LabEx4 then put LabEx4.this

Comment: Code is working fine. whats the problem. Can I post the full activity code as per your xml?

Comment: alertDialog.setTitle("Typing Result!");
         **here i want to add some info like this..Frankie Jones Igat, Your Typing Speed is:119203 miliseconds..have 1 button below..
         alertDialog.setMessage(String.valueOf(count));

Comment: SO simply replace Typing Result! string with your string. Like String s1 = "Frankie Jones"; String s2="your typing speed"; alertDialog.setTitle(s1+" "+s2);

Comment: As per your requirement you have to create custom layout for pop up. I am updating the code As Per Your Requirement. Please have a look and you can change the design from xml as per your choice